Concerns about being asked followup questions at Schengen Immigration
I recently got a 6-month, multiple-entry visa from the German embassy. I travelled to Germany, the Netherlands, and France with my wife.
At the Berlin airport, I was asked for the purpose of my visit, and I replied that I was coming for tourism. I was asked to provide hotel bookings. On being asked how many days was I going to stay in Germany I said 10 instead of 4, since I thought the officer was asking for the total duration I would stay in Europe.
She checked my hotel bookings, immediately saw that I was booked for 4 days, and questioned me about it. I clarified that I was travelling to Amsterdam after Germany, and she smiled and asked for all my bookings, after which she stamped our passports and recorded our fingerprints.
Does this mean that I was flagged or something, since I didn't answer correctly when asked how many days I was going to stay in Germany? Will this create an issue in future Schengen visa applications?

She didn’t record your fingerprints, she compared them with those associated to your visa (remember you had to have your biometrics taken when you applied for your visa? That’s when they recorded them). They possibly also compare them to the data in your passport.

To me, they seems standard questions, and standard replies. If the officers had problems with you, you will be questioned much more, and possibly a supervisor will give a second opinion. (they job is to block, not "flag", which it is not very useful)

The usual question I hear is "how long will you spend in schengen" even, so it's pretty normal that even a frequent traveler might be tripped up by this question and answer the same way you have. I'd say you haven't done anything wrong, and as any confusions have been cleared up there's nothing to worry about. IME they always check your fingerprints if you have a tourist visa.

I also felt the same but the usual doubt abt being flagged sometimes exists for not answering their questions.  I hv also read that if someone was flagged they would be subject to a secondary verification for an hour and then be released if satisfied.  This happens a lot in the US. hope i didnt mess up for future visa approvals.

So it seems i am good to go for the future applications. No flags

It's a good idea to answer in complete sentences.  "How many days will you be in Germany?  10" -> you've misunderstood the question and given a false response.  "How many days will you be in Germany?  We'll be in Europe for 10 days." -> you've answered the wrong question, but there's no falsehood or deception.  They still can ask a followup to get the particular datum they wanted, but it's hard to imagine "truthfully answered the wrong question" ever giving you a black mark.

Thanks for replying back. I misunderstood the question clearly. Its a good thing i had my bookings for other schengen countries. A few people here said flagging doesnt exist.they can either block or let u enter

So.they cant flag people? Their job is to accept or deny entry ? I read somewhere that if i had an issue on entry i would definitely have been questioned on exit

I need to travel to spain next month. Can i be assured there is no issue since i have a multiple entry visa? I wasnt asked any questions when i exited

But if i was lets say flagged. Wouldnt i be questioned on exit?

If you are interested in knowing what information got stored about you, you can make a request for data stored in the Schengen Information System. However, based on the information you provide here, it sounds like your admission to Germany was pretty ordinary (you were asked a couple of followup questions but provided apparently-satisfactory answers and were admitted without any additional processing). It can not be said for certain, but to me it sure sounds like you have nothing special to worry about.

Can the schengen embassy open ur file and evaluate your documents again after you have got the visa? Or is it verified prior to issuing visa?


Does this mean that I was flagged or something, since I didn't answer correctly when asked how many days I was going to stay in Germany? Will this create an issue in future Schengen visa applications?

No, there is simply no legal basis or computer system to record anything like that. In the Schengen area, borders guards cannot restrict or qualify an admission. Unlike border guards in other countries they do not even have a say on the duration of your stay. Because of the way the EU works, what gets shared between countries is also a lot more transparent than whatever national systems might exist in the US or elsewhere.
If there is any doubt about your intentions, the main thing border guards can do is refuse entry. If they do that, depending on the country and circumstances, they can also invalidate your visa (which gets recorded in the VIS) or impose a ban (which gets recorded in the SIS). If that ever happens, you should get specific paperwork stating exactly what the decision was.

Thnks for ur reply . I feel more confident reading these answers. I thought i didnt answer the question on how many days i was in germany . In fact even if i didnt have a booking i still have a 6 months visa .i cud have extended my hotel stay in germany more than 4 days. Plus i exited from paris . Total stay 11 days. I am allowed to stay 90 days
